# Impossible retrive file names from directory

Tags: python

3 different incoherence for same unavailability to retrive the list of file in a directory:

1st. the result of getCSV function is empty; When I step into getCSV with the debugger, at 1st cycle for, I receive this error: `Internal StopIteration`
so stop debugging

```
import os
import globe
dir_csv = 'D:\\Documenti\\Develope\\Python\\AI\\Previsone\\All_csv\\'
#dir_csv = 'D:\Documenti\Develope\Python\AI\Previsone\All_csv'

def getCSV(dir_csv):
    csv = []
    for root, directories, file in os.walk(dir_csv):
        for file in file:
            if(file.endswith(".csv")):
                csv.append(file)
    return csv

files = getCSV(dir_csv)
```

2nd. Other trial: instead of Os library I used Globe.

```
getFile = glob.glob(dir_conf+'_Titoli Generati[1-9].txt')
getCSV = glob.glob(dir_csv+'*.csv')
```

and despite getFile that return what inquired, getCSV return empty string

3rd. `files = os.listdir(dir_csv)`
the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato: 'D:\\Documenti\\Develope\\Python\\AI\\Previsone Titoli\\Titoli_csv'
```

Comment: Have you try to change the path format ? `D:/Documenti/Develope/Python/AI/Previsone/All_csv`

Comment: yes just now.. but no way !

Answer (score 0):

I assume that getCSV would return the file name and not the file object

I think your problem lays here:

```
 for file in file:
```

I would change the code a bit :

```
csv=[]
list_of_files_in_folder=os.listdir(dir_csv)
for file in list_of_files_in_folder:
          if(file.endswith(".csv")):
                csv.append(file)
```

Comment: you right, but as explained @ point 3rd, also os.listdir() return an error , even changing the path declaration in many accepted fashions ... very strange...

Comment: Did you tried my code?

Comment: yes I did: same stuck as mine: "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3]...."

Comment: Just to understand ,in which stage you get the FileNotFoundError?  Do you a debugger ?  what do you get as values in list_of_files_in_folder

Comment: @ listdir call level

Comment: You work on windows evn?

Comment: yes, ion win 10